# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on external hard drive using downloaded ISO on USB

Tags: ubuntu

I am a Newbie and I have, managed to, installed Ubuntu 14.04 (via downloaded ISO image on an EMTEC 16 GB USB) on to a 1TB Seagate hard drive attached to a Lenovo-50 that has a Windows10 operating system.

The install was completed successfully according to Ubuntu.

But I have a problem now with this computer.

I can boot (by changing the Windows10 UEFI boot sequence) the following USB's:

1. The Emtec USB (above) which has the downloaded ISO Ubuntu 14
2. A second Emtec 16 GB USB which has GPARTED program installed. 
              which I have used to view Devices and Partitions on the 
              Ubuntu 14 installed 1 TB Seagate external hard drive

However, this external drive, refuses to boot. I have spent 2days erasing and re-installing successfully and trying to get it to boot, with no success.

Can anyone give me a solution or a path to one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibilty that you did not install it for (U)EFI, and therefore it cannot be booted. Try setting your computer to legacy/BIOS boot mode or "EFI with CSM" (fancy term for EFI with legacy) (this can be done in the BIOS or whatever it is named for EFI) and then booting from the USB.

Edit: [This tutorial](http://trickiknow.com/lenovo-g50-bios-setup-install-windows-8/) might help.

Comment: Thanks, Ivo, for that quick response. I went in and looked in my laptop. Under Boot it says: Boot Mode -UEFI.  And the only other boot mode available other than EFI-PXE Network  and EFI USB is Windows Boot Manager. So there must be some other cause

Comment: I don't think that is the boot mode, those sound like the boot devices. A boot device is somewhere you can boot from (for example, a partition on a hard disk or USB drive). The boot mode should be somewhere in the BIOS settings. Also, I have edited my answer with a tutorial that might help.